# OpenGL or Canvas?

Tags: 2d, android, opengl-es

I'm writing a 2D snake-like game for android (Hungry Birds, already in the market), and now I'm wondering if I should port it to OpenGL so that the performance can stay stable while I continuously add additional features to it. I'm still an apprentice (17yo), so I don't know any "complicated" math yet (matrix transformations, vector math etc). Should I risk the porting?

Comment: If you plan on going into any more gamedev, linear algebra and vector math is invaluable.

Comment: Yeah I'll learn that in school as I go along, and I'll also probably go to a university too, but at the moment I don't have the spare time to learn it by myself. I've had a bit of linear algebra in school. Do I need understanding of these things for OpenGL or is there a lib for dummies?

Comment: You can start OpenGL without deep knowledge in matrices nor vector maths. Orthographic projection and glTranslate/Scale/Rotate will be enough for start.

Comment: I've just about finished reading this book (http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Android-Games-Mario-Zechner/dp/1430230428/) and it's a great way to ease yourself in to OpenGL with all the maths etc.  He makes it look really easy!  (I'm in no way affiliated with the author - I just really rate this book)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want (or have time) to learn all the math, i'd suggest you keep on working with Canvas, or using a Game engine that wraps OpenGL and do all the complicated math for you (for example [Andengine](http://www.andengine.org/))

Comment: Thanks, didn't think there where any engines for android... I'll look into it.

Comment: You may also want to check out libgdx for an engine.